# why my div is not hiding again after any click outside of that div?

Tags: asp.net

i have created a hidden div..and after clicking my log in button the div appears..but after clicking anything outside of that div i want to disappear my div...how???

my button

```
<asp:Button ID="loginbutton" runat="server" Text="Login"  OnClientClick=" return   someFunction();"/>
```

my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunction() {
    $("#logdiv").show();
   // document.getElementById('logdiv').style.display = "block";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to disappear after it has been clicked? Otherwise you can add an `onClick` function to everything on the page to disappear it, or have have a `onMouseOut` on it so that when the mouse is moved outside it executes a function to disappear.

Comment: when i will click my login button,the hidden div will be shown..but when i will click outside of this div, the div will disappear again...hope you understand..wilf

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the document click, and hide it as:

```
document.onclick = function()
{
    $("#logdiv").hide(); 
}
```

if you use jQuery the same is

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    $("#logdiv").hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this javascript function to the visible elements outside of the div: *(not very good at ASP, sorry)*

```
...onclick="document.getElementById('logBox').style.display='none';"...
```

e.g.

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('logBox').style.display='none';"><div>
```

You can also try adding it to the `<body>` tag - but that might include the thing itself when it is clicked on.

This would end up with something similar to what is shown [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/go626iyh2t5zdwk/c.html)